# Iterating JSON object in typescript and adding object to array issue

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have the following JSON object assigned to *allDepartments*, which is an array of a custom datatype  contactItem:

```
export interface contactItem {
    id : number;
    position: string;
    name : string;
    email : string;
    extension : number;
    phone : Text;
    department: string;
}

public allDepartments: contactItem[];//interface defined in conatctService
```

This is allDepartmnets:

:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "position": "Director of Pathology and Laboratory Medicine",
        "name": "Dr. Niall Swan",
        "email": "niallswan@svhg.ie",
        "extension": "4798",
        "phone": "012214798",
        "department": "General"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "position": "Laboratory Manager",
        "name": "Donal Murphy",
        "email": "D.Murphy@svhg.ie",
        "extension": "4510",
        "phone": "012124510",
        "department": "General"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "position": "Laboratory Manager",
        "name": "Donal Murphy",
        "email": "D.Murphy@svhg.ie",
        "extension": "4510",
        "phone": "012124510",
        "department": "General"
    },....
```

When the department key is equal to *biochemistry* in an *contactItem* I want to add the contactItem object to an array of contactItems called *biochemistry* :

```
public biochemistry : contactItem[];

//itearte array and assign biochemistry contacts 
   console.log("contacts.page.ts: trting to get biohemistry  data...");

   for (var contact in this.allDepartments){
     console.log("contact = " + this.allDepartments[contact].department);
     if (this.allDepartments[contact].department="biochemistry"){
       this.biochemistry.push(this.allDepartments[contact]);
       console.log("biochem object: " +this.allDepartments[contact]);//array of objects
     }

   }
   })
```

However an exception is thrown :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'this.biochemistry.push'

The syntax for pushing an object to a Typescript array seems ok, so not sure what the issue is. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the typing of `public biochemistry : contactItem[];` is wrong, and that you're ignoring some TS warnings, but there isn't enough context in the question to see where you're expecting that property to be defined on the instance

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, there is not enough context, but some points: You probably shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate the array more so because you don't use the index, just use a `for...of`. Second, you have a typo here `if (this.allDepartments[contact].department="biochemistry"){` where you assign `"biochemistry"` to every department, you need double equals to check for equality(or better use triple equals): `if (this.allDepartments[contact].department === "biochemistry"){`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to initialise  the array:

```
public biochemistry : contactItems[] = [];
```